# Non-blocking Queries in Spring Data for MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to execute non-blocking database queries through Spring Data accessing a MongoDB using [MongoDB's Async Client API](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/).

So far I've only seen the possibility to return a

- `java.util.concurrent.Future`
- `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture`
- `org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture`

and annotate the query method with `@Async`, e.g.

```
public interface UserRepo extends Repository<User, Long> {

  @Async
  ListenableFuture<User> findByName(String name);

}
```

but the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async) clearly states that the actual `[...] query execution will occur in a task that has been submitted to a Spring TaskExecutor`. So it's not really non-blocking but just decoupling my thread using a thread pool which doesn't scale very well.

Therefore my question:

*How to execute the queries in non-blocking mode using the MongoDB Async Driver's NIO Features?*

The only workaround I see so far is to get rid of Spring Data and implement the database queries by my own using the [Mongo Async Driver API](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/). But hopefully I'm just missing something and there is a straigth-forward answer out there. ;)

Comment: what was your solution in the end ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky I've been using the reactive api to solve my concrete problem, cf. my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with [Spring Data Kay M1](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/23/first-milestone-of-next-generation-spring-data-released) finally a reactive API has been introduced that allows non-blocking data access using the [ReactiveCrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html) interface.
There's a good [blog post of the Spring team about it](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data).
It's nowadays also mentioned in the [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async) but keep in mind if you already started your project by using the @Async feature to not mix it with the new reactive api as the docs clearly states: *"Asynchronous query execution is different from reactive query execution and should not be mixed."*